# Syntax error, delete token "else"

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public class Basic {

    public static void main (String []args){
        int first = 1;
            if (first == 1);{ 
                System.out.println("I did it");
            } 
            else {
                System.out.println("I didnt do it");
            }
```

I dont know what to do, is there a mistake and i followed all the steps in the tutorials i'm watching. It just says delete the token

Comment: I know this isnt a pretty clean code, im a beginner

Comment: (first == 1); this is incorrect, you dont need semicolons

Comment: Every open curly bracket must be closed. It's like math. Does `(1 + 2 (3+4` make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon after `if (first == 1);`

The semicolon after makes the `if` statement finished and the block after `{}` is not a part of if.So the `else` part is complaing about the non-existence of if because else cannot exist without if

Comment: What about the missing `}`

Comment: OP only mentioned `Syntax error, delete token “else”` so I was giving answer only for that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon after `(first == 1)`

Comment: What about the missing `}` ?

Comment: He just didn't put all of his code. This is what I assumed.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the obviously misplaced `;` and finish all your opened brackets. Try this:

```
public class Basic 
{

    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        int first = 1;
        if (first == 1)
        { 
            System.out.println("I did it");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("I didnt do it");
        }
    }
}
```

If you have problems with brackets, you can configure Eclipse to automatically put closed bracket under each other like in the example.

The semicolon you have placed there ended your `if` statement, so it had no effect on the code between the brackets. You can imagine (Java purists will pardon the simple explanation), that after `if`, there is only one command or command block allowed. The brackets will group more commands to one block.

Try this example, it will explain you how it works.

```
int i=1;

if (i==1)
    System.out.println("I should be here when i==1");
else
    System.out.println("Will this output be printed out? No, this is else section!");

if (i==2)
{
    System.out.println("I should be here when i==2");
    System.out.println("Will this output be printed out? No! Condition was not met, because i==1 and we are in the block");
}

if (i==2)
    System.out.println("I should be here when i==2");
System.out.println("Will this output be printed out? Yes, because the commands are not in the block!");


if (i==2);  //WATCH OUT, there is semicolon that terminated if statement
System.out.println("Will this output be printed out? Yes, because that semicolon has terminated the if statement!");
```

Comment: what signals that a block has ended?

Comment: Block starts with `{` and ends with `}`. If you don't end the block, then your compiler or IDE (Eclipse) will tell you.